# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Response")

Tags: xml, rest, spring-boot, soap, xsd

Need to produce Soap service which consumes a rest service producing application/XML.

### Following is the error reported

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Response"). Expected elements are

`<{http://www.amfampoc.com/Vehicle}getAllVehicleMakesRequest>, 
 <{http://www.amfampoc.com/Vehicle}response></faultstring>`

### XSD File

```xml
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="getCountryRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Response">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Count" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="Message" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="SearchCriteria" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Results">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="VehicleTypesMakes">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="MakeId" type="xs:int" />
                                        <xs:element name="MakeName" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element name="VehicleTypeId" type="xs:int" />
                                        <xs:element name="VehicleTypeName" type="xs:string" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

### Sample XML Response from service

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <Count>24</Count>
       <Message>Response returned successfully</Message>
       <SearchCriteria>Make: merc</SearchCriteria>
       <Results>
          <VehicleTypesMakes>
             <MakeId>449</MakeId>
             <MakeName>Mercedes-Benz</MakeName>
            <VehicleTypeId>2</VehicleTypeId>
            <VehicleTypeName>Passenger Car</VehicleTypeName>
          </VehicleTypesMakes>
          <VehicleTypesMakes>
            <MakeId>449</MakeId>
            <MakeName>Mercedes-Benz</MakeName>
            <VehicleTypeId>3</VehicleTypeId>
            <VehicleTypeName>Truck</VehicleTypeName>
         </VehicleTypesMakes>
       </Results>
    </Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML response is using default namespace for Response element, which is not valid against the XSD. It should be in namespace `http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service`. In short, there should be something like `<Response xmlns="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service" ...>` in the response.

Comment: thanks for your swift reply. Currently Response received from 3rd party not sending xmlns="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service" . Is there something that can be done in xsd side?

Comment: This is not a good practice, but you can simply remove the targetNamespace attribute from the XSD and see if it works. This results in your XML elements having literaly no target namespace.